# Django Create Recurring Payments

Tags: python, django

Good day,

I have two models, one for the destitute and the other for credit payments to be submitted to a bank for deposit into the destitute's acc.

I need some guidance creating a function that loops through the **Destitute table**, creates recurring payments every month, and records them in the **Credit table**. Logic is if the destitute is above the age of 50 they get paid 2500k if below the age of 50 they get paid 2000k. If there is a Django package that can help achieve that would be great.

```
class Destitute(models.Model):
    GENDER = (("male", "male"), ("female", "female"))
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    acc_no = models.CharField(_("Bank Account"),max_length=50)
    age = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=1)
    sex = models.CharField(
        _("Gender "), max_length=64, choices=GENDER)
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(_("Date Joined"), auto_now_add=True)

        def __str__(self):
            return self.name

class Credit(models.Model):
    credit_title = models.CharField(_("Payment Title"), max_length=50)
    payee = models.ForeignKey(
        Destitute, related_name="destitute_paid", on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True)
    total_amount = models.DecimalField(
        blank=True, null=True, max_digits=12)
    payment_date = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.credit_title
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There're planty of packages you can use: [django-crontab](https://github.com/kraiz/django-crontab), [django-background-tasks](https://github.com/arteria/django-background-tasks), [django-apscheduler](https://github.com/jarekwg/django-apscheduler) and etc.